# Transfer data from one JSF page to ProcessAction() method of FacesPortlet

Tags: jsf, portlet

Here is what I am trying to do.
I want the data from jsf page1 to be available in jsf page2 which is a popup window opened by page1.
Both have separate managed beans.
I tried using sessions but it resulted in null pointers.
I somehow managed to get the data in page2 using window.opener() in javascript.
Now I want this data to be available in the processAction() method of FacesPortlet.
Tried using request.getParameter, request.getAttributes, all in vain.
After a lot of research I somehow managed to send some hard coded data in processAction() method. But I am unable to send the value from page1.
Here is how I am sending the hardcoded value.

```
<form name="uploadbaseline" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<portlet:actionURL><portlet:param name =         "page" value = "someval"/></portlet:actionURL>">
```

This is followed by the other fields inside the form.
I get the value in processAction() method like this

```
System.out.println("valuefrompage1"+request.getParameter("page"));
```

This returns "someval".
Now I try to assign the value from page1 using javascript using the following code.

```
var val =     window.opener.document.getElementById("BaseLine:EngineModel").value;      
var actionval = "<portlet:actionURL><portlet:param name='page' value=" + val.value + "/></portlet:actionURL>";      
document.uploadbaseline.action = actionval.value;
document.uploadbaseline.submit();
```

This returns the value "+ val.value +" as it is and not the actual value in the "val" variable.

Please guide me in the right direction.
Keenly looking forward to your replies.
Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any confusion in the way I have posted my query. I'll be more than eager to clarify the same.

Comment: Is there any way of getting the parent page value other than window.opener and query string??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally.
The problem lies in the enctype attribute of my form.
This prevents me from accessing the page fields using the regular request.getParameter.
This needs to be handled in a different way.
Here is how.

```
for (Iterator requestItems = upload.parseRequest(request).iterator(); requestItems.hasNext();) {
    item = (FileItem) requestItems.next(); // Get each item in the request
    if (!item.isFormField()) {
       //handle the file data
    } else {
       System.out.println((String)item.getString());
    }
}
```